# Trouble loading model in codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter, model

For some reason whenever I try and call a function in my model from the controller it returns the error `

```
PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined method Test_model::ajax() in /var/www/CodeIgniter/application/controllers/blog.php on line 19, referer: http://localhost/CodeIgniter/index.php/blog`
```

Here is my model named test_model.php in the models folder

```
<?php
class Test_model extends CI_Model {

    function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    function ajax(){
        echo 'ajax successful';
    }
}
?>
```

Here is my controller that is trying to use the ajax method in the model above

```
 <?php
    class Blog extends CI_Controller {

        public function index()
        {
            $data['title'] = "My Real Title";
            $data['heading'] = "My Real Heading";
            $this->load->view('blogview', $data);
        }

        public function comments()
        {
            echo 'Look at this!';
        }

        public function ajax()
        {
            $this->load->model("test_model");
            $this->test_model->ajax();
        }
    }
    ?>
```

So why am I getting the undefined method error?

**EDIT**
By sugesstion i changed my controller to the following to include loading the model in the action of index to

```
<?php

    class Blog extends CI_Controller {

        public function index()
        {
            $data['title'] = "My Real Title";
            $data['heading'] = "My Real Heading";
            $this->load->model("test_model");
            $this->load->view('blogview', $data);
        }

        public function comments()
        {
            echo 'Look at this!';
        }

        public function ajax()
        {
            $this->test_model->ajax();
        }
    }
?>
```

This returns the error

```
 PHP Fatal error:  Call to a member function ajax() on a non-object in /var/www/CodeIgniter/application/controllers/blog.php on line 19, referer: http://localhost/CodeIgniter/index.php/blog
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pay attention with the file name:

Correct

```
model/test_model.php
```

Incorrect

```
model/Test_model.php
```

AND

If the class's name is Test_model, then you have to call $this->load->model("Test_model");

Like this:

```
public function ajax()
{
$this->load->model("Test_model");
$this->Test_model->ajax();
}
```

Of course, to call the method:

```
http://yoursite.localhost/index.php/blog/ajax
```

Comment: I tried it both with upper and lower case of the model and the same error still persits

Comment: Change the file name. /var/www/CodeIgniter/application/models/test_model.php

Comment: Tried changing the file name to an uppercase verison but according to the user guide http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/models.html model file should be lowercase while class name should start with a captial.

Comment: I had my file name correct the whole time and I've tried changing the model to Test_model and test_model in the ajax function both returned the same error of having undefined methods.

Comment: Weird for some reason your orginial answer now works... I swear I had it like that before... lol anyway thanks man for the answer

Answer (score 1):

You have to punt inside your action `index` the call to the model in the right way
Models names are case-sensitive.
Try to change this:

```
$this->load->model("test_model");
```

to this and put it in the action `index`:

```
$this->load->model("Test_model");
```

must be uppercase

**UPDATE**
Change inside your controller your action ajax

```
public function ajax()
        {
           $this->load->model("Test_model");
            $this->Test_model->ajax();
        }
```

Comment: Have you put the load model in the right action of the controller? @AustinDavis

Comment: update answer put the load model in the index action of your controller @AustinDavis

Comment: in this case I think index is the action (the name of the function that you want to run to load your view) @AustinDavis

Comment: Do you mind updating your answer to how you think it should be implemented becuase I don't really understand what your suggestion is. Do I but the $this->load->model("test_model"); in the index function?

Comment: Yes you have to put this code: $this->load->model("Test_model"); int he index function of your controller before the other code, try it @AustinDavis

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/34101/discussion-between-austin-davis-and-alessandro-minoccheri)